# Saving workspace in Julia with JLD2

Tags: julia, save

I am trying to write a mutable object that comes out as a result from a function that I wrote.

I am using JLD2 package version 0.4.3 and using a function as below. `res` is the mutable object that I am trying to save.

```
@save "example.jld2" res
```

After running the code, I keep getting the error. I have tried reinstalling the JLD2 package but I keep getting the same results.

```
type DataType has no field mutable
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

I expected to get a .jld2 file containing the variable `res`, but I keep running into errors.

Comment: Update the package. This JLD2 version is over 2 years old. Please see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/jld2-error-type-datatype-has-no-field-mutable/78651